# How to separate overlapping curves more effectively?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, accuracy

So, I am trying to create a Neural Network which will effectively separate 2 Gaussian curves with somewhat different means and standard deviations. My basic aim is, for some given input vector the Neural Network will select 2 points from the 2 Gaussian curves (selection based on the input vector) and compare them, and output a value depending on the Gaussian curve which gives a greater value.

Now, if I implement a simple Neural Network with 2 hidden layers the accuracy of my predictions is about 68.75% for 2 Gaussian curves with ***N(0,1)*** and ***N(0,2000)*** respectively and 100% for ***N(0,1)*** and ***N(500,1)***  (my NN outputs `0, 1` and hence I can easily measure accuracy by `true_positives/total_samples`). Clearly more the overlapping curves, less the accuracy as the NN cannot distinguish between the 2 curves.

I have tried increasing the number of hidden layers, changing learning rate but still there is no improvement in accuracy. I am using back-propagation with momentum.

So my question is what structure, learning algorithm and modifications in the Neural Network will help me to effectively separate 2 curves which is kind of overlapping for a better accuracy?

EDIT 1: I have generated the data myself for testing purposes, in real situation I will only have an input/output pair from a black-box, and all I know the black-box follows some Gaussian distribution. Also the input vector has to be arranged in some sort of way, and then if we fit the curve to it, it turns out to be Gaussian.

EDIT 2: I am looking for possible hints. Any experienced person in this field might make a guess for some better methods. I know you cannot have a definite method, so suggestion of methods which might work are welcome.

Comment: This looks like a job for a simple Bayes classification, i.e. computing $p(y=1|x)=\frac{\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1, \sigma_1)p(y=1)}{\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1, \sigma_1)p(y=1) + \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_2, \sigma_2)p(y=0)}$ rather than a neural network...

Comment: https://content.artofmanliness.com/uploads/2014/01/14.png :)

Comment: @JanKukacka nopes, cause I have a black box model and I am trying to approximate, i only have input output pair....all i know is the device follows some Gaussian dist. but i don't know what it is

Comment: @JanKukacka also I am generating the data myself for testing purposes..in real life I will only have the black-box...thanks for your help though..really appreciate it

Comment: Okay, so the parameters of the gaussians are unknown, but if you know there are two gaussians, you can try fitting them to your data to infer their parameters...

Comment: @JanKukacka the problem is not exactly linear in nature...say we have a normal dist followed by the black box, so in real life pdf at 4 > pdf at 5...but this is not the case in this BB, the BB has to find out which number maps to which part of the G curve, effectively it has to adjust even the x-axis

Comment: Adjust the x-axis? I don't understand... I'll try recap: You have a device which produces for each input an output from one of two unknown gaussians distributions, and you are trying to figure which of the two distributions produced the output. Right?

Comment: @JanKukacka ya but i also don't know which input vector maps to which point on the Gaussian curve, the input vector is not the x-axis it is some randomized numbers, which if arranged in a certain way can form an axis to which the output will be gaussian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the impression that neural networks are not the right tool for the task. Instead, I think you need to identify the source gaussians in the data using [expectation maximization of a gaussian mixture model](http://aishack.in/tutorials/expectation-maximization-gaussian-mixture-model-mixtures/). This step outputs means and covariance matrices of the two gaussians that generated the data.

In the second step, you can use a simple Bayesian classifier and evalue probability of the output coming from either of the gaussians ($y=1$ or $y=2$) as:

$$p(y=1|x)=\frac{\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1, \sigma_1)p(y=1)}{\mathcal{N}(x|\mu_1, \sigma_1)p(y=1) + \mathcal{N}(x|\mu_2, \sigma_2)p(y=2)}$$